# Display number as Ordinal number in 'word form' with NumberFormatter PHP class?

Tags: php, numbers, number-formatting, ordinal, numberformatter

If I'd like to display a given number as ordinal number, I'd do it like this:

```
<?php
    // Needs 'php5-intl' package to be installed on Debian/Ubuntu

    $set_format = numfmt_create( 'en_US', NumberFormatter::ORDINAL );

    // '3' is displayed as '3rd'
    echo numfmt_format( $set_format, 3 );

?>
```

But if I'd like to display a given number as ordinal number **in word form** (e.g. first, second, third, etc.) using a **built-in PHP function/class** like `NumberFormatter`, how do I do that? Is it possible?

**Related Links:**

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.create.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.format.php

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You want to be using the `SPELLOUT` format style, rather than`ORDINAL`.

The next problem is how to tell the formatter to use the particular ruleset that you are interested in; namely `%spellout-ordinal`. This can be done by using [`setTextAttribute()`](http://php.net/numberformatter.settextattribute).

**Example**

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$formatter->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::DEFAULT_RULESET,
                             "%spellout-ordinal");

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo $formatter->format($i) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Output**

```
first
second
third
fourth
fifth
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, there's a small mistake. It'd be `echo $formatter->format($i) . PHP_EOL;`. Am I right?

Comment: Absolutely. In writing, I shortened the variable name (to make the second line fit on SO's narrow page) then thought better and wrapped the line... leaving that typo artefact.

Comment: P.S. SO answers are wikis. Feel free to fix typos if/when you spot them.

Comment: One last thing. Do you know how I can get the first letter capitalized (First, Second, Third...)? I mean do I need to use something like `ucfirst()` or is there a built-in way?

Comment: `ucfirst()` would be okay, I'd assume.

Comment: Does that support Non-English languages? I'm trying Arabic but still return the usual SPELLOUT